# Google App Engine, Django, CloudSQL and Images

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Currently porting some Django projects over to Google App Engine.
I am using Python 2.7, Django 1.4 and Google CloudSQL.

The problem I have is with an Admin driven Gallery.
Handling image upload seems to be a problem, using ImageField I am getting an erorr on mkdir command as GAE wont allow a local write.

I am a little stuck and solutions seem quite confused, I am using CloudSQL due to its compatibility with the old MySQL databases that ran the sites previously.

How can I get the gallery back up and running without local storage? I have been researching use of GAE blobstore, but posts seem quite varied and unhelpful.

Cheers
Kevin

Comment: The solution *is* the Blobstore. Have you read the actual documentation, rather than relying on blog posts? Exactly *what* are you finding "confused"?

Comment: Well the Google documentation I have been reading for blobstore is not Django specific (as far as I have found so far) also I am looking for a simple fix for the admin side of things without much upheaval of the existing code. In my models previously I simply referred to ImageField and that was pretty much it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to rewrite ImageField to use the BlobStore instead of files.

A quick google search suggests someone might have already done this:
http://blog.uysrc.com/2011/02/12/image-uploads-working-with-models-imagefield/